# Call python script in Julia

Tags: python, optimization, julia

I have a Gurobi model that I have implemented in Julia. This model is dependent on data input missed bags:

```
Function deterministic_model_test(Path_to_data)
    include(Path_to_data)
    model = Model(Gurobi.Optimizer);

# constraints...
    end
```

I want to run a stochastic model, using the deterministic model (the structure you can see in the code below).

**My problem** is that all of the data preprocessing and adds stochasticity to data that is necessary is made in python (as it is easier using numpy and vectorization), so is it possible to call a python scripts that does all the preprocessing save the output it in a csv file and load the new data into Julia?

```
best_missed_bags = missed_bags
for h=1:H # number of iterations
    x = deterministic_model_test(best_missed_bags)
    missed_bags_pr_flight[s,fa] = []
    missed_bags_day[s] = []
    for s=1:S
        # stochastic arrival times

        RUN PYTHON SCRIPT WITH DATA PREPROCESSING --> update CSV file
        Missed_bags = LOAD NEW CSV FILE INTO JULIA

        # Compute number of missed bags for simulation given the assignment
    
    end

    # Update z if fewer less bags with the given assignment (asve the assignment)
    if best_missed_bag>missed_bags_day[h]
        best_missed_bag = missed_bags_day[h]
        
        # update missed_bag matrix
        for fa in Fa 
            best_missed_bags = mean(old_miss_{f,i}, new_miss_{f,i})
        end
    end
end
```

I hope you can help :-)

Answer (score 1):

This documentation link should be of help: [Running External Programs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/running-external-programs/)

For example, suppose `test.csv` has the following content:

```
Name,Hieght
Alice, 1.69
Bob, 1.77
```

Then you can use it within Julia with:

```
julia> using CSV

julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = CSV.read(`cat test.csv`, DataFrame)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ Name     Hieght  
     │ String7  Float64 
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │ Alice       1.69
   2 │ Bob         1.77
```

In your case, you would want instead of `cat test.csv` to run `python some-script.py` which outputs the CSV to standard output.
If this is a problem, the process can be done in two stages, writing the CSV in python with `run(...)` command and reading it as above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It makes sense - thank you! But How would I run the python script in Julia - if I have a python script called "data_prep.py" that save a CSV file, and I want to run that pyscript in Julia followed by csv.read. When I try the command run(python data_prep.py) it gives an error... :-) 

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It would be `run(\`python data_prep.py\`)`. Also have a look at the link in the answer - Julia support for running external commands is quite extensive and good.